# How to check auto_gcroot object for nullptr

Tags: c++-cli

I want to check if my C++/Cli managed auto_gcroot is null or not. Here's how I proceeded :

```
auto_gcroot<RefClassA^> m_a;

if (static_cast<RefClassA^>(m_a) != nullptr)
    {
        .....
    }
```

The problem is that I get an error :

> 'No suitable conversion from 'auto_gcroot to object^ exists'

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on VS2012. When I substitute `String` for `RefClassA`, it compiles fine. Do you have any other errors that might be the root cause?

Comment: It is a smart pointer type, just `if (m_a) {}` gets the job done.  But that upsets the IntelliSense parser, `if (!!m_a) {}` is perhaps a bit to grody.  `if (m_a.get()) {}` is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I'm not able to reproduce this on VS2012.

However, [`auto_gcroot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177048.aspx) has a [`get`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177053.aspx) method that returns the object as a plain reference. You should be able to compare that to `nullptr`.

```
msclr::auto_gcroot<String^> m_a;

if (m_a.get() != nullptr)
{
    // ...
}
```